# Naming inconsistency in GNOME `.directory` and `.application` files

Tags: gnome, gtk3, freedesktop, gtk2

I'm using Debian 11 with GNOME 3.28 and I noticed that there are a lot of naming inconsistencies in `.directory` and `.application` files.

For example, the `name` field of `Utility.directory` is `Accessories` while the `name` field of `X-GNOME-Utilities.directory` is `Utilities`

There is also a `GnomeScience.directory` whose `name` field is just `Science`. (I mean, why not name it `X-GNOME-Science.directory` like the one above?)

I was wondering if such naming practice is intentional or it is just a legacy issue due to poor maintanance?